# Android Listen for/Detect entry into the log

Tags: android, logging, broadcastreceiver

Is it possible to listen for entries to the log?
Ie is there a broadcast intent for when a log entry is appended?

Comment: Printing to the logcat is essentially identically to printing to the standard out. So no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no Intent.

use below code :

```
try
    {
        Process mLogcatProc = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        mLogcatProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"logcat", "-d"});

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mLogcatProc.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        final StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
        String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator"); 

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            log.append(line);
            log.append(separator);
        }
        String w = log.toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),w, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

and you will need it's permission :

```
android.permission.READ_LOGS
```

Answer (score 1):

If by "the log" you mean LogCat, no, there are no broadcast `Intents` for appending entries to LogCat.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'm trying to get to the bottom of solving an earlier requirement whilst making an app.

I'd like an app that detects when other apps are started. In its simplest form each time any app is started, my app displays a view or message. I want to extend this, but for the time being, just to get it working can you think of a way of doing this?

I was going to try and detect if the log was written to, then look at what was written and look for a "main" intent. I know what i'm after can be done, just not sure how

where would you start if this were your task? cheers

Comment: @Ian: "I'd like an app that detects when other apps are started." -- as far as I am concerned, this is a privacy violation.

Comment: I can see how it would be, but there are a few App Lock apps out there that show a password screen when other apps are started.
Search for App Lock or App Protector in the market. I want to develop something similar with a few more features but have drawn a blank as to how they've achieved this fundamental part!

Comment: @Ian, Check out `ActivityWatcher`...It wont tell you when an App is started, but it's close enough.